# ¿Cómo traducir la frase "There is a first for everything"?

Tags: traducción

La frase *"There is a first for everything"* expresa un elemento de sorpresa, que algo ha pasado por primera vez y es un poco raro que haya pasado. Intenté expresar este concepto el otro día y solamente me salió un *"es la primera vez que"* que me parece muy lejos. Google Translate sugiere: "hay una primera vez para todo" que es bastante literal pero me suena muy mal.

Comment: He oído e incluso usado varias veces la traducción que propone Google. Realmente, no están traduciendo las palabras, sino la expresión completa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La sentencia dada omite "first time."
Si ponemos "there's a first time for everything," la traducción literal es "hay una primera vez para todo," que es lo que el traductor google nos sugiere.

Para ellos "there's a first for everything" tiene sentido porque comúnmente omiten muchas palabras, así como también nosotros tenemos nuestras formas de expresar sus dichos, ellos también las tienen.

Si no te gusta, entonces podemos poner

> para todo, hay una primera vez.

esta última es la más usada (al menos donde yo vivo), pueden haber variaciones diferentes dependiendo del país de habla hispana.

Comment: Vale, lo acepto. No sé porque pero pensaba que exisistía algo más idiomático.

Answer (score 2):

> Siempre hay una primera vez para todo.

That's as close as I can think of.